# Resolve in uibmodal /route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-routing, angular-ui-modal

I have this code:

```
var b = 1

var a = $uibModal.open({
    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
    templateUrl: 'enteModal.html',
    controller: 'enteCtrl',
    resolve: {
        obj: {"id" : id, "description" : "blabla"},
        id: eval(b),
    }
});
```

And it works, but I dont know why.
I've read the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) of resolve, that should be a map *key* : *String* or *key* : *function*.

eval(id) and {..} are an integer and an object, not a factory function, as far as I know, Resolve uses angular.injector().invoke(), but on object or integer returns error

But the controller resolves correctly **obj** and **id**. Why it works with object or integer? The doc is wrong? or uibmodal resolve is not the same resolve of route?

Comment: You misunderstand what docs says. Everything is correct there. {String} is a key type.

Answer (score 0):

Your resolve object needs to be a map of string: function, where string is the name of the dependency that will be injected into your modal's controller, and function is a factory function that will be used to provide that dependency when the controller is instantiated.

```
obj: {"id" : id, "description" : "blabla"},
id: eval(b),
```

In your case keys are 'obj' and 'id' and their value are {"id" : id, "description" : "blabla"} and eval(b) resp.

Comment: eval(id) and {..} are an object and an integer, not a factory function as you said. Why does it works? as far as I know, Resolve uses angular.injector().invoke(), but on  object or  integer returns error

Comment: The resolve property is an optional map object / [ array of existing service names ]. All the keys of the map object can be injected to the controller as a dependency. The key would be a simple string, and its value can be either a function or string. If string is provided, Angular will assume that it’s an existing service and inject that particular service to the controller. If the value is a function, it will act as a factory function and the return value will be injected to the controller.

Comment: in my case the values of the keys are an object and integer, NOT A STRING OR A FUNCTION, but its working, why?